# PHP set value to null when return

Tags: php, variables, return-value

This question probably weird but I can't answer anywhere. Do I need to set value to `null` when returning (save memory)?

```
      ...
      $output =  $DB ->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...", $param);

      if (empty($output))
      {
          throw new Exception('Error');
      }
      else
      {
          return $output;
          $output = null;
      }
```

Or just return `$output`? And whats happens with this variable after return? Still uses a memory?

Comment: You cannot Execute code after return .

Comment: the code after return won't ever be executed

Comment: No, that line of code won't even be executed because it comes after the return

Comment: If you want to do that, use `try-finally`.

Comment: Let PHP do its own garbage collection, it's pretty efficient for freeing up memory when variables are no longer in scope, such as when you return from a function

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Are you trying to just return `null`?

Comment: I think better you don't let enter into the conditions and return it is probably a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your immediate question: No, you don't NEED to set local variables to `null`.  The memory will automatically be released.  To see this in action try something like this:

```
function foo() {

  $output =  $DB ->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...", $param);

  if (empty($output))
  {
      throw new Exception('Error');
  }
  else
  {
      print 'Memory usage:'.memory_get_usage();

      $output = null;   // Do this before returning!

      return $output;
  }
}

...

print 'Memory Usage before:'.memory_get_usage();
foo();
print 'Memory Usage after:'.memory_get_usage();
```

I believe your concern is really, "Should I clean up resource variables (e.g., DB queries, etc.)?  The answer to that question is "Yes" and setting the variable to null in that case is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will free up any memory used once you return from the function. You can test this yourself by using `memory_get_usage`:

```
<?php
function bigArray() {
    $bigArray = range(1, 1000000);
    showMemory('Big array assigned');
}

function showMemory($where) {
    echo $where, " - using: ", memory_get_usage(), " bytes", PHP_EOL;
}

showMemory('Start');

bigArray();

showMemory('End');
```

The exact byte values will change depending on which exact version of PHP, but for me this produces:

> Start - using: 340080 bytes
>
> Big array assigned - using: 25510064 bytes
>
> End - using: 340080 bytes

As you can see, once we return from the function, the memory goes back to the initial value.

Example: https://eval.in/869171

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
  else
  {
      return $output;  // Code leaves this function or method
      $output = null;  // So this never runs
  }
```

There's no need for it, just return your results!